# Can we Upgrade the old project version to the latest version 0.69 without adopt new architecture?

Tags: react-native

Can we Upgrade the old project version to the latest version 0.69 without adopting new architecture?

do have some links for reference?

Answer (score 1):

After reading some docs about updating from the versions that I had (***0.67 -> 0.69/0.68***) I read this post from the React Native page ([An update on the New Architecture Rollout](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2022/03/15/an-update-on-the-new-architecture-rollout)). This post is about the new release that fully introduces the new Architecture, in this post you can see that it is **optional** to use the new Architecture only by changing some variables.

So, to answer your question, you can update to RN-0.69 and keep the old architecture and if you want to try the new architecture you need to change some variables for iOS and Android.